# How do you use 3D graphics in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, 3d, game-physics

I am wondering how app developers create games with 3D animations and graphics. Does anyone know how those games are made, and can it be done with android studio?

Comment: you definitely need to have a look at Unity 3D...

Comment: @Vaibhav Mule: He is clearly asking about modern techniques, metodoloogies and tools for developing 3D games - fast and easy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with Android Studio.

If you wanted to hand-code it, you would just create a GLSurfaceView, and draw objects into it. Here's a basic tutorial: [Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html)

But, you would *never* hand-code it in real life. To make even a simple 3D game, you would want to use a game engine like [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) or [jPCT-AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/).

Any decent 3D engine will have tools for porting to Android. And many of them have communities that can offer support and troubleshooting.